# Intellij Access static variables from another class within package without their classes' names?

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, static-variables

When I was in Android Studio and typed whatever static variables in other classes, they were automatically imported and there were no class names in front of them. However, now I am in a Java project in IntelliJ and it does not recognize whatever such variables I type. How do I make it behave like Android Studio? 
What's more frustrating, when I do ClassName.staticVariable, it sometimes does not work. Did I miss some settings or something?

Here is an image about the problem.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K40UH.png)

Comment: `import static`.

Comment: I know I could do that but it is just so much simpler if it imports itself when I am typing.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ (from v16 onwards) had had this configuration option:

> **Add unambiguous imports on the fly**
>
> Select this check box to have IntelliJ IDEA automatically add imports that can be added without user intervention.

You can select this from `Preferences > Editor > General > Auto Import`. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

With this and `static methods and fields` enabled IntelliJ will auto import statics. For example, hitting return in the following screenshot adds an import for the referenced static and the resulting code includes that static **without** its qualifying class e.g. `AN_UNAMBIGUOUS_STATIC` instead of `Statics.AN_UNAMBIGUOUS_STATIC`:

[image]

Comment: @AndrewLin could you be more specfic about what "it does not work" means?

Comment: I uploaded an image in the question. Please take a look

Comment: Have you enabled these configuration options: `Add unambiguous imports on the fly` and `static methods and fields`? If so, then if IntelliJ is not auto prompting you with fully qualified statics then I must be misunderstanding your question.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Should I smash my computer

Comment: I think you do understand my question.